# jQuery AJAX & an ASP.NET web service works locally but not remotely

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Interesting one here. I have an ASP.NET 1.1 project that contains a web service in it. I'm using jQuery's AJAX functionality to call some services from the client. This is what my code looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'foo.asmx/functionName',
    data: 'foo1=' + foo1 + '&foo2=' + foo2,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        //do something with my xml data
    },
    error: function(request, error){
        //handle my error

    }       

});
```

This works great when I run the site from my IDE on localhost. However, when I deploy this site to any other server I get a parsererror error from jQuery. It does not appear to even call my service as I dropped in some code to write a log file to disk and it's not making it there.

The same exact XML should be returned from both my localhost and the server I deployed to.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you check if you have javascript error ?

Comment: How about authentication? did you change the authentication for that web service folder?

Comment: the AJAX call is using the same domain as the site you're on, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer to this. After some debugging with Firebug I noticed that the server was throwing back some error HTML. I looked at my server side error logging and the exception was "Request format is unrecognized."

After a bit of digging around I discovered that the following change to the web.config corrects the error:

```
<system.web>                
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

Now I am a bit interested in the fact that my localhost does not have that web.config entry and works regardless. If anyone understands that a little better I'd like to know why.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: To possibilities: The Visual Studio IDE debugger uses a native machine.config file, which can work like a set of default settings that web.config can take on when it cannot find certain settings. So, local and hosted versions of machine.config may differ. Also, this could depend on which version of IIS is being used locally and on the server. In IIS6 and lower, there are settings that can be set in IIS which cannot be set in web.config. However, I think that web.config can have full control over any IIS7 settings. So, anything lower than IIS7 can be unpredictable if relying soley on web.config

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "parsererror" from jQuery?

My first two passes would be:

1- use firebug to get more error details 
   http://encosia.com/2009/03/04/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/

2- convert your data string to a json object '{"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2"}'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that foo.asmx gets you to the proper location, did you change folder structures at all?

Comment: It's the correct path. No changes when deployed. I even tried hard coding the path to see if this was the cause but no dice. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined the XML that's being returned when the application is deployed to make sure that it's the same?

For those who are wondering when you'd get a jQuery parse error, it looks like it's related to XML-returning web services: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/a97f10ae30824fba?pli=1